# An easy application of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

If $\int_0^{2x} f(3t)dt$ $=$ $\frac{x}{\pi}\sin \pi x$, then I have to find $f(\frac{1}{2})$.

Let $y = 3t$ and then we get $\frac{1}{3}\int_0^{6x} f(y)dy$ $=$ $\frac{x}{\pi}\sin \pi x$.

We then differentiate to find $2f(6x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\sin \pi x + x\cos \pi x$.

Then we put $x = \frac{1}{12}$ to find the answer.
Have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The last term is wrong. The derivative of $\sin \pi x$ is $\pi \cos \pi x$.

Comment: @Äres OP has edited the question after I posted this answer.